# Grails SQL Error on run

Tags: mysql, grails, dynamic-finders

I am trying to make a simple web app for a school project in Grails.  I can access the server, save, delete, and everything else, but whenever I first run the app I am getting masses of SQL errors thrown at me.  I am using Grails 2.0.3 and mysql-connector-java-5.1.19.

I get the following error and many others like it:

Error 2012-04-25 14:28:54,009 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - Unsuccessful: alter table character_trait add index FK93D74D785F2F8048 (character_traits_id), add constraint FK93D74D785F2F8048 foreign key (character_traits_id) references character (id)

Error 2012-04-25 14:28:54,009 [pool-5-thread-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character (id)' at line 1

And when querying using the findby dynamic finders:

Class
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Message
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character this_ where this_.player_id=1 limit 1' at line 1

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: It would help to include the relevant portions of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHARACTER` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL.  It needs to be quoted to be used as a table or column name.  You can quote it in the table mapping like so:

```
class Character {
    static mapping = {
        table name: '`character`'
    }
}
```

Comment: @ataylor..same thing is happening with me for column name `to`, please tell me how I need to declare this in static mapping, I did as follows:
    `static mapping = {
  to name:'`to`'
 }`
but did not work for me. Please tell me correct way for solve this problem for column name.

Comment: @ataylor..I have solved that problem, bu using 

`static mapping = {
  to column: '`to`'
 }`

thanks for your answer,  it helped me a lot.